# Examples of tags?

Tags: syntax, sociolinguistics, pragmatics

I'm planning to do a study on tag-switching, but from the literature I read, tag-switching is commonly only found in sentences with '*you know*', '*I mean*', '*right?*', and '*isn't it?*'.

Are there other examples of tags? Or can we just consider *tags* as *fillers*?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing two different categories, [Tag questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question) and [fillers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_%28linguistics%29).

**You know** and  **I mean** are fillers, while I'd consider **right?** and **isn't it?** to be tag questions. The purpose is quite different, and consider:

> You're John, *aren't you?*

Here I'm not just "filling" the sentence, I'm asking for confirmation, while fillers are there to basically let your interlocutor know that even if you're not uttering something concrete, you're not finished speaking, like:

> I was... **uuh**, **I mean**, I really was... **like**... about to call you.

Comment: Based on Mahootian (2006) in Encyclopedia of Language and Linguistics, tag switches involve the insertion of tag forms such as 'I mean', 'you know', 'isn't it?', etc, e.g. 'Él es de México y así los criaron a ellos, you know.' and 'It was a good performance, (wasn't it)?' What are the examples of tag forms actually?

Comment: _Tag switching_ is not yet a term that has made it into the syntactic vernacular. It seems more pragmatic, and extrasentential; it might be useful to analyze errors caught in this way, but I don't know of any source that details all the common English markers. Since it's a repair sequence at speed, it's likely to be improvised from some frozen components.